# Chat application (in Web Garden): SignalR + Redis vs WebService

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, signalr

I have created a chat for an ASP.NET WebForms application. I used SignalR (without Redis) to create the chat component. Everything worked accordingly on my dev machine.

Once the application got deployed to the IIS the SignalR chat stopped working. The reason I found is that the IIS server is configured as a web garden and SignalR is built to work on a single worker (more explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757525/signalr-lost-messages-if-iis-configure-with-more-than-1-worker-process)).

After reading the link above and some search I found that I could use SignalR + Redis to overcome the Web Garden issue. But, I also saw examples of AJAX WCF Services powered chat apps.

Which of the two is a better way to build a chat application, taking into account the Web Garden issue and the fact that deployment is done on a Windows machine (I read Redis works best on Linux)?