# SignalR Groups not always communicating

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have encountered a strange issue while working with SignalR. It may be something I am doing wrong or an incorrect expectation on my part.  I have posted the example code an issue description on git

https://github.com/boblautenbach/SignalRGroups

Thanks
-bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, So I did some additional research.  I found a SO q/a [SignalR lost messages if IIS configure with more than 1 worker process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757525/signalr-lost-messages-if-iis-configure-with-more-than-1-worker-process/12778690#12778690) that mentioned the same concerns and even though it wasn't related Azure, it was very relevant.  If you have more than one instance of your Signalr hub Azure Web App, which can be set as seen below, then you will run into the issue I mentioned. Essentially, client connections made to instance A will not see instance B connections. If you do need more that one instance of your Hub, you will need to implement one of the scale-out options here http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr.  I test this using the Service Bus scale-out option and it worked great (my site currently has 2 instances).

[image]